# Animate shape in typography mask SVG

Tags: svg, snap.svg, clip-path

For my new website, I want to mask a morphing shape inside a typography like clip path property. I have done the morphing but not the mask, any idea ?

I put 2 photos of my example and a jsFiddle.

My Example :
[image: image exemple]
jsFiddle exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/aw8zvsbn/32/

```
s = Snap(1000, 500);
s.attr('fill', 'red');
s.attr({ viewBox: "80 230 340 100" });

var path = s.path("m238 324c-19.4 0.618-33.4-27.3-47.6-37-8.27-5.66-35.8-21.4-28.5-35 2.51-4.67 18.8-4.3 22.4-5.5 11.4-3.83 15.8-10.8 25.8-16.6 29.7-17.2 32.2 14.8 58.1 11.5 8.36-1.06 13.3-11.8 21.4-14.3 10.6-3.22 20.8 1.61 31 5.74 18.4 7.48 25.4 13.8 13.5 36.2-12.2 22.9-27.6 9.32-43.3 23.5-7.57 6.78-7.33 16.8-16 23-9 7-26 9-37 9-12 0 15 0 0 0z");
path.animate({ d: "m187 302c-13.3-0.667-12.9 9.71-27.5-0.5-9.9-6.91-6.5-13.6-3-28.2 3-15-12-37 3-44 11.1-5.07 35 16.9 54 20s26.4-20 45.2-17.2 11.1 15.4 34.3 16.8c20.6 1.2 60.8-0.555 55.7 22.7-6.36 29-44 23-61.7 33.5-10.3 6.1-25-13.4-33.2-6-10.3 9.38-21.3 14.2-33.3 15.2s-21-12-34-13z" }, 6000, mina.linear);
```

Any help would be precious.
Sorry for my english, I'm French

Comment: use <mask> or <filter>

Answer (score 0):

You just mask the animated blob with some `<text>`.

Plain SVG example below. I'll let you translate it to a Snap script.

```html
<svg viewBox="80 230 340 100">
  <defs>
    <!-- some text we will use for masking the red blob,
         and also for the green text in the background.
         We define it here once so we don't have to repeat it twice. -->
    <g id="mytext" font-size="50" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="bold">
      <text x="100" y="270">CLOTHING</text>
      <text x="150" y="310">BRAND</text>
    </g>
    
    <!-- Define the mask that we will use to show only part of the red blob -->
    <mask id="textmask">
      <use xlink:href="#mytext" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!-- Display an instance of the text in green -->
  <use xlink:href="#mytext" fill="limegreen"/>

  <!-- The red blob masked with our text mask -->
  <path d="M187,302C173.7,301.333,174.1,311.71,159.5,301.5C149.6,294.59,153,287.9,156.5,273.3C159.5,258.3,144.5,236.3,159.5,229.3C170.6,224.23000000000002,194.5,246.20000000000002,213.5,249.3C232.5,252.4,239.9,229.3,258.7,232.10000000000002C277.5,234.90000000000003,269.8,247.50000000000003,293,248.90000000000003C313.6,250.10000000000002,353.8,248.34500000000003,348.7,271.6C342.34,300.6,304.7,294.6,287,305.1C276.7,311.20000000000005,262,291.70000000000005,253.8,299.1C243.5,308.48,232.5,313.3,220.5,314.3C208.5,315.3,199.5,302.3,186.5,301.3C186.5,301.3,187,302,187,302C187,302,187,302,187,302" fill="#ff0000" mask="url(#textmask)"></path>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for help Paul It work like a charm ! :)
Any idea for animate the shape ?
In my jsfiddle i use the framework snap.svg for this.
Thanks

Comment: I didn't do a Snap version because I am not that familiar with it.  I decided to leave that to you :)  Just use the Snap functions to recreate the structure of my example.  The mask should work for an animated blob.

Comment: Ok i will try for the animation and thank's again man !
You'r great :)

Comment: GSAP is great for web animation, including SVGs: https://greensock.com/get-started-js. Google recommends GSAP for all but simple CSS animations.